# deciding on what and how to use for character offsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rangy

I have following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg9nccde/7/) which basically has `jqxGrid` with *Modes of Transportation* single column and `jqxPanel`on the left side of it with some text content containing words which are there in the Modes of Transportation column.

**Current Situation:**

When a user clicks on the cell value of the column, the clicked word gets highlighted in the paragraph. The problem with this approach is that, it is highlighting all the words in the column which I don't want. There can be scenario in the text content where I want to highlight only specific words and not all the words present in the paragraph.

I have jSON data available which has the `start` and `stop` character offsets values for each of the words present in the `Modes of Transportation` column as for example,shown below:

```
{
    "webservice_status": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
    },
    "documentContent": [{
        "webservice_status": null,
        "id": "4321",
        "wordTo_highlight": "Car",
        "document_id": 678767,
        "date_value": "2016-04-27",
        "doc_content": "                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n\n                  Sedan Final Report- 4/28/2016 14:38 CDT -\n\n         CASE: Z-77-7654\n\n                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n",
        "stop": 645,
        "start": 638

    }, {
        "webservice_status": null,
        "id": "4321",
        "wordTo_highlight": "Bus",
        "document_id": 678767,
        "date_value": "2016-04-27",
        "doc_content": "                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n\n                  Sedan Final Report- 4/28/2016 14:38 CDT -\n\n         CASE: Z-77-7654\n\n                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n",
        "stop": 2890,
        "start": 2883

    }, {
        "webservice_status": null,
        "id": "4321",
        "wordTo_highlight": "Car",
        "document_id": 678767,
        "date_value": "2016-04-27",
        "doc_content": "                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n\n                  Sedan Final Report- 4/28/2016 14:38 CDT -\n\n         CASE: Z-77-7654\n\n                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n",
        "stop": 1156,
        "start": 1149

    }, {
        "webservice_status": null,
        "id": "4321",
        "wordTo_highlight": "Train",
        "document_id": 678767,
        "date_value": "2016-04-27",
        "doc_content": "                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n\n                  Sedan Final Report- 4/28/2016 14:38 CDT -\n\n         CASE: Z-77-7654\n\n                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n",
        "stop": 2970,
        "start": 2963

    }, {
        "webservice_status": null,
        "id": "4321",
        "wordTo_highlight": "Airways",
        "document_id": 678767,
        "date_value": "2016-04-27",
        "doc_content": "                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n\n                  Sedan Final Report- 4/28/2016 14:38 CDT -\n\n         CASE: Z-77-7654\n\n                                                 Company Name:Car Transportation\n\n                                                 id:    000004321\n\n                                          Vehicle Report\n\n\nExcellent Condition:                Z-77-7654             Received Date/Time:       4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n                                                   Collected Date/Time:      4/27/2016 13:02 CDT\n\n",
        "stop": 3744,
        "start": 3737

    }]
}
```

where, `doc_content` is the text content that I have it in my JS Fiddle (It's different in JSON just for testing purpose).

**My Goal:**

How can I link the `start` and `stop` values in the `Modes of Transportation` column with the specific words in the text content? Is there a way, Rangy library can come into picture here? I saw [Rangy Range](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Range) documentation but it looks like they are generating start and end character offsets based on user selection. I couldn't find anything specific to what to do if I already have `start` and `stop` character offsets values as shown above in the JSON. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **key parts** to solve your problem are:

- process your text by the end
- perform string replacement (using [String.prototype.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)) based on each word indexes (`start` & `stop`) in the text

**Note**: if you process your text by the beginning, it will shift the indexes of the next words 
as you introduce additional characters (html markup).

To achieve this, you will need to organize your raw Json data returned by your webservice.
You should regroup the occurrences of each word together and sort them by decreasing positions.

```
// Organize you data by word and sort by decreasing position to get something like this:
var items = [
    { 
        wordTo_highlight: "Test", 
        positions: [
            {start: 44, stop: 47},
            {start: 0, stop: 3}
        ],
        doc_content: "Test text for a proof of concept...just for Test purpose"
    },
    {
        wordTo_highlight: "elements", 
        positions: [
            {start: 38, stop: 45},
            {start: 28, stop: 35},
            {start: 5, stop: 12}
        ],
        doc_content: "Some elements to highlight: elements, elements"
    }
];

function _getHighlightMarkup(word, position) {
    return '<span class="highlight" ' +
            'id="' + position.start + '-' + position.stop + '">' + 
            word + 
            '</span>'
}

// Iterate over all items above to build one text version for each distinct word
// and display it in the debugger console
items.forEach(function(item) {

    var docContent = item.doc_content;

    item.positions.forEach(function(position) {
        docContent = docContent.substring(0, position.start) + 
            _getHighlightMarkup(item.wordTo_highlight, position) + 
            docContent.substring(position.stop + 1);
    });

    console.log(docContent);

});
```

Each word has been identified using the provided `start` and `stop` and each word is now identifiable by its `id` attribute, so you can use this to highlight only the one
you want (not all of them at the same time)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) So, are you suggesting to change the JSON format of the web service? 2) Also, I was wondering how I can make use of the `start` and `stop` values which I am getting in my JSON response. 3) Do you think the Rangy library could come into picture here?

Comment: @John 1) It is up to you. You can either change the format from the server side or post-transform it when you receive the response on client side. 2) No sure to understand you...the code I provided is using the `start` and `stop` values to identify the words. It is not using a Regex as you use in your JSFiddle. 3) I don't really know this library but it seems a bit over complicated for what you need to do. If you really want to use it, maybe you can have a look at the [Text range module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For my second question, I was referring to the JSON data that I posted in my question. So basically my question is, if we already know the `start` and `stop` values from the JSON response, then is there a need to determine these values again?